# How to get value from hidden input in ng-repeated div using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have controller which send data to UI and map them using ng-repeat directive.Next thing that i want to do is to bind that data with hidden input form,and send it in another function in controller when click event occur.Any idea how to accomplish this?
My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="card card-block" ng-repeat="admin in showAdmins">
<h3 class="card-title">{{admin}}</h3>
<input type="hidden" ng-value="{{admin}}" ng-model="username"/>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="searchAdmins(username)">SeeProfile</button>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
$scope.searchAdmins = function(username){

    //To do
};

github.users('admins.php').then(function(users){

    $scope.showAdmins = users;
    console.log($scope.showAdmins);

});
```

Comment: You don't need any hiddent, input, this is not jquery: just pass directly to ngclick the value you need `admin` or `admin.username`.

Comment: Thanks,now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
<div class="card card-block" ng-repeat="admin in showAdmins">
    <h3 class="card-title">{{admin}}</h3>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="admin"/>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="searchAdmins(admin)">SeeProfile</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/IzJkvLJoTHLtVzobWPpZ?p=preview

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testctrl',function($scope) {

var users = [

```
{
  user : 'User1'
}, {
  user : 'User2'
}, {
  user : 'User3'
}
```

];

$scope.showAdmins = users;

$scope.searchAdmins = function(user){

alert(user);
 }

});

Html

```
<div  ng-repeat="admin in showAdmins">
<h3 >{{admin.user}}</h3>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="searchAdmins(admin.user)">SeeProfile</button>
```

Thank you,
Chaitanya